# How to remove the parenthesis and apostrophes when using a function to assemble a vector with name?

Tags: python, list, function, vector

I want to print the list without getting the parenthesis and the apostrophes.

```
def vec_print(list, name):
    name += " ="
    return name, list

print(vec_print([1.20,4.50,4.40],'vec1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
def vec_print(lst, name):
    return name + ' = ' + repr(lst)

print(vec_print([1.20,4.50,4.40], 'vec1'))  # -> vec1 = [1.2, 4.5, 4.4]
```

I changed the name of the argument from `list` to `lst` because the former is the name of a type built into Python and it's best to avoid redefining any of those (for one thing it confuses people reading your code).

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis are printed, because you return a tuple, and the representation of a tuple is with `(...)`.

Just return a string:

```
def vec_print(list, name):
    return "{} = {}".format(name, list)

print(vec_print([1.20, 4.50, 4.40], 'vec1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the list items after mapping them to strings, and use the string formatter for output:

```
def vec_print(lst, name):
    return '{} = {}'.format(name, ', '.join(map(str, lst)))
print(vec_print([1.20,4.50,4.40], 'vec1'))
```

This outputs:

```
vec1 = 1.2, 4.5, 4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. There are a couple reasons that your question isn't getting a positive reaction here.

- You didn't actually ask a question. You can't just say what you want and expect the community to eagerly help you.
- You didn't tell us what you've done so far to solve this on your own.

I assume that you got this output:

```
('vec1 =', [1.2, 4.5, 4.4])
```

but were hoping for

```
vec1 = [1.2, 4.5, 4.4]
```

There are a couple ways to get what you want, but you should first understand why this happened. In your `vec_print` function you return *two* values: `return name, list`. In python, if you do that you are actually returning a tuple of the return values. When you printed the return value, you were printing the representation of a tuple of two elements.

There are two paths to the solution:

1. Don't return a tuple. This would look something like: `return name + repr(list)`
2. Join the elements of the tuple and print that instead of the tuple. The simplest way is to use the `*` operator to deliver the tuple elements to the print function: `print(*vec_print([1.20,4.50,4.40],'vec1'))` This works in python3 because print is a function. In python2 this will be an error because `print` is a statement and not a function unless you do `from __future__ import print_function`